# Making a command button open in new tab

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton, commandlink

How do I make this open in a new tab:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection >                                                                                  
                 <apex:commandButton value="Amount Spent Over Time" action="https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/AmountSpent2?core.apexpages.request" reRender="newWindow" onComplete="openWindow()"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Time Since Last Order" action="https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/TimeSinceLastOrder2?core.apexpages.request" reRender="newWindow" onComplete="openWindow()"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Time Since Last Contact" action="https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/TimeSinceLastContact?core.apexpages.request" reRender="newWindow" onComplete="openWindow()"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Custom Orders Query" action="https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/CampaignQuery?core.apexpages" reRender="newWindow" onComplete="openWindow()"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: I also tried using the window.open JS function and called it using the onClick attribute of the command button, didn't work.
<script>
        function openpage () {
           window.open(https://c.cs83.visual.force.com/apex/AmountSpent?core.apexpages.request, '_blank')
        }
 </script>
    <apex:form >        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Select a campaign to setup">
            <apex:pageBlockSection >                                                                                  
                 <apex:commandButton value="Amount Spent Over Time"  onClick="openPage()"/>

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Any console errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with a CommandLink as:

```
<apex:commandLink target="_blank" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" 
action="https://c.eu6.visual.force.com/apex/AmountSpent2?core.apexpages.request" value="Amount Spent Over Time"/>
```

Comment: You have sufficient reputation to add such one liners as comment.Try to be more descriptive when providing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Create New Contact (Salesforce style button target _blank)

```
<apex:commandLink target="_blank" styleClass="btn" style="text-decoration:none;padding:4px;" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.NewContact)}" value="Create New Contact" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open and give target blank.

```
<script>
    function openpage () {
       window.open(URL, '_blank');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Nothing, @shravanboddula

Comment: @MGS This is just the javascript. You have to write the button with onclick as the above function.

Answer (score 0):

Using apex:commandLink changes your styling due the the syntax of an anchor, text inside an anchor is annoying to deal with especially when the anchor is a btn. Additional CSS is then required.

I used this approach with an onclick,
removed the action,
added a rerender="none".

This works for me:

```
<apex:commandButton id="GoogleMaps" styleclass="btn btn-success font-weight-bold" style="height:60px;" value="NAVIGATE" rerender="none"
    onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination={!Case.Location__c}+&travelmode=driving','_blank');">
</apex:commandButton>
```

Allowed me to keep consistient styling with all other buttons.

All that said it sounds like this didn't work previously so maybe Salesforce will regress it in the future????